# How to find xpath if class contains a space

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have a site, I need extract some information from class, but class have a space, how I can do it?

```
    <div class ="product-item view-list " data-ht="2" data-pc="13">
```

Thank you for a help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use XPath, this should work:

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " product-item view-list ")]')
```

Or, you can use CSS:

```
response.css('div.product-item.view-list')
```

Answer (score 0):

Below elements

```
<div class ="product-item view-list " data-ht="2" data-pc="13">
<div class ="product-item view-list" data-ht="2" data-pc="13">
```

are same. There is no space in the class name as such. So you need to just use

```
response.css(".product-item.view-list")
```